# XANES simulation software/code besides FEFF?

Tags: spectroscopy

I need to generate the XANES region spectra of the Pt L3 edge of a theoretical Pt6 crystal with adsorbed atoms (such as hydrogen, oxygen, etc). It is to generate theoretical references as described in this paper: https://doi.org/10.1039/b927120c

However, based on what I have read, I would need the FEFF8 code but I only have access to FEFF8-lite (free version, limited to EXAFS analysis) and the Demeter package which is for analysis of experimental data, if I'm not mistaken. Is there an alternative software (free) or method to generate or calculate a theoretical XANES spectra?

Comment: There might be someone here who can answer, but since this question is largely about finding modeling software, it may be a better fit on [Matter Modeling SE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Try FDMNES
http://fdmnes.neel.cnrs.fr/ Team
SINThe FDMNES project is developped in the SIN team, Institut Néel, CNRS, Grenoble, France, by: Yves Joly, Yvonne Soldo-Olivier and Oana Bunau Very important numerical improvements were included by: Sergey Guda, Alexander Guda, Alexander Soldatov, Mikhail Soldatov
Southern Federal University, Rostov-on-Don, Russia An extension for EXAFS, FDMX, is due to: Christopher Chantler and Jay Bourke
Melbourne University, Australia